# how to handle conflict resolution interceptor in the sync service for timestamp based synchronisation

Tags: c#

see this code and tell me any suggetions for timestamp based synchronization
when data changed for particular record in a particular table in both client and server databases.After i Synchrosize there conflict will arise.at that time i need timestamp based synchronisation.

Is it possible?

if possible suggest me..

Thanks in advance...

```
#region SyncService: Configuration and setup
public class DefaultScopeSyncService : Microsoft.Synchronization.Services.SyncService<DefaultScopeOfflineEntities> {
    public static void InitializeService(Microsoft.Synchronization.Services.ISyncServiceConfiguration config) {
        config.ServerConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ListDbConnectionString"].ToString();
        config.SetEnableScope("DefaultScope");
        config.AddFilterParameterConfiguration("userid", "User", "@ID", typeof(System.Guid));
        config.AddFilterParameterConfiguration("userid", "List", "@UserID", typeof(System.Guid));

        config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
        config.EnableDiagnosticPage = true;
    }


    [SyncConflictInterceptor("DefaultScope",EntityType=typeof(LookupType))]
    public SyncConflictResolution ConflictHandler(SyncConflictContext context, out IOfflineEntity mergedEntity)
    {
        context.ResponseHeaders.Add("ConflictInterceptorFired", "true");
        mergedEntity = null;
        return SyncConflictResolution.Merge;
    }
}
#endregion
```